# Are there any websites that collect WPF/XAML Templates/Styles of common controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just writing another TabControl ControlTemplate and wondering if there are good websites for Wpf Styles/Templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WPF themes on codeplex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Themes)

[Xaml templates](http://www.xamltemplates.net/)